# Ipad/iphone..action sheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I used picker view and date picker with action sheet and it is working fine in iphone.
I upgraded my iphone app for ipad. i set action sheets autoresize property but it is not displaying in ipad and when i rotate iphone.Here is my code

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Payment Type"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];


// Add the picker
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,185,0,0)];

picker.delegate = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    // note this is default to NO
picker.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[actionSheet addSubview:picker];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 700)];
actionSheet.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
[picker release];
[actionSheet release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One point you should keep in mind using Actionsheet in iPad is that it is displayed as PopOver ViewController.It is the default behavior of Action Sheet in iPad.

Cheers

Comment: So how can I use same in ipad and iphone??

Comment: You need to make use of the same code as a popover Viewcontroller if you want to use in iPad

Comment: ok you mean I have to use popover viewcontroller which can work in iphone also?I dont want to write different code for ipad and iphone.

Comment: I would recommend writing different code for the iPad and iPhone. It just makes it a cleaner experience. You have all your math/logic/networking/parsing in a separate framework of classes and then just call them from your iPad/iPhone view controllers. It's much nicer.